# Using pipes in Boost unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I'm trying to write Boost unit tests for my server.
I want to launch my server - start() launches the server in a thread - open a client, connect it and try to download a file.

I'm doing this this way:

```
tftp_server* my_test_server;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE (tftptest) // name of the test suite is tftptest

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE (test1)
{
    my_test_server = new tftp_server(69);
    my_test_server->start();

    FILE *in;
    char buff[512];


    if(!(in = popen("tftp", "w"))){
        exit(1);
    }

    fputs ( "connect xx.xx.xx.xx\n", in );
    fputs ( "mode binary\n", in );
    fputs ( "mode\n", in );
    fputs ( "get truc.txt\n", in );

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL)
        printf("%s", buff);

    sleep(10);

    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}
```

1) Creating and launching the server,

2) using the system TFTP client (I'm on OSX),

3) waiting 10 seconds.

It doesn't work : It only executes the client after the test is done.

```
Running 1 test case...
Server started on port 69
Server running.

*** No errors detected
$ Using octet mode to transfer files.
Transfer timed out.
```

Any idea how I could solve my problem ?

Thanks !

EDIT

```
void tftp_server::start()
{
    LOG_INFO("Server running.", 0);
    boost::thread bt(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &_io_service));
}
```

Comment: where is your client? How do you use threads? Does `my_test_server->start();` start a thread?

Comment: Yes, it starts a thread (I've updated my question with the implementation). The client is the OSX system client (I usually use it in a terminal).

Comment: Ok, and where do you start the client? I'd say that it should work if you started the client in the same test method.

Comment: I'm starting the client with popen in the same test method (as you can see).

Comment: Don't use `exit` in the testing framework. Use `BOOST_FAIL` instead. In addition, there seems to be some cleanup missing: destroy the ftp-server, preferably via construction on the stack, or if need be via smart pointers. In addition, you seem to not close the pipe.

Comment: Thanks Arne Mertz ! Closing the pipe has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added close, and it works.
Thanks to Arne Mertz.

```
if(!(in = popen("tftp", "w"))){
    exit(1);
}

//...

while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL)
    printf("%s", buff);

pclose(in);
```

Comment: I'd guess that either the server is waiting for an EOF that does not occur without closing the pipe, or there is some flushing involved (I have no idea of pipes) that gets triggered by the close. You should consider using/writing RAII classes for stuff like this (smartpointers, fstream,...), since it is one of C++'s strengths.